# Mixing protobuf-lite and protobuf-java. NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, protobuf-java

my module includes two dependencies (3rd party libraries), one of them contains `protobuf-lite` and the other one `protobuf-java`. It looks like there is duplicated `AbstractParser` class which results in:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.shouldDiscardUnknownFields()'
```

I cannot change anything in these libraries and i need to use them both within single test class.
How could I solve this conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `protobuf-java` includes what in `protobuf-lite`. If yes, then exclude the lite version. If it is not the case, the only solution that you have is to shade the third-party library and relocate the classes that come from the lite version.